# Can I view the logging output by preview / debugger in Foundry?

Tags: foundry-code-repositories

Using Foundry authoring, is it possible to see the logs output by my code when using the Preview or Debugger?  In particular logs output by log4j or Python [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

Answer (score -1):

Logger utilities do not output into the preview agent.
You can technically output to  the debugger, but it does require to understand what handler is used there.

Comment: Sorry but I ain't digging this kind of answer at all